# Angular – edit/remove element in a Subject Array

Tags: angular, subject, subject-observer

I have a Subject of Array of Users

```
  private _currentHeroes = new Subject<Hero[]>();
  currentHeroes = this._currentHeroes.asObservable();
```

- **My goal is to edit only 1 element of the array without subscribing**

**Function of power up the user in my service**

```
powerUp(id: number) {
return this.http
  .post<Hero>(environment.apiUrl + 'heroes/powerUp/' + id, {})
  .pipe(
    tap((updatedHero: Hero) => {
      this._currentHeroes.next(
        // I would like to edit the specific element in the array and than sort them by the power.
      );
    })
  );
  }
```

**Function of delete the user in my service**

```
  delete(id: number) {
return this.http.delete<Hero>(environment.apiUrl + 'heroes/' + id).pipe(
  tap((deletedHero) => {
    this._currentHeroes.next(
      // Here I delete the specific element from the array
    );
  })
);
  }
```

**If the Subject was BehaviorSubject so I would do this:**

```
    powerUp(id: number) {
    return this.http
      .post<Hero>(environment.apiUrl + 'heroes/powerUp/' + id, {})
      .pipe(
        tap((updatedHero: Hero) => {
          this._currentHeroes.next(
            this._currentHeroes.value
              .map((hero: Hero) =>
                hero.id === updatedHero.id ? updatedHero : hero
              )
              .sort((a, b) => a.currentPower - b.currentPower)
          );
        })
      );
  }

  delete(id: number) {
    return this.http.delete<Hero>(environment.apiUrl + 'heroes/' + id).pipe(
      tap((deletedHero) => {
        this._currentHeroes.next(
          this._currentHeroes.value.filter(
            (hero: Hero) => hero.id !== deletedHero.id
          )
        );
      })
    );
  }
```

But my goal is to achieve the same while using Subject instead of BehaviorSubject.

I tried getting the value of the subject but it's not possible since it's a Subject. I tried searching online but unfortunately, I didn't find any useful solution for my needs.

Does anyone encounter this issue? Or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are working on a service, then you can have a reference of array you need to modify in service attr.

```
heroes = [];
```

then, after every operation, you can modify that values and then emit with Subject or Behavior Subject or whatever you want to use.

```
powerUp(id: number) {
return this.http
  .post<Hero>(environment.apiUrl + 'heroes/powerUp/' + id, {})
  .pipe(
    tap((updatedHero: Hero) => {
        //modify data reference, to add, update or delete value
        // in this case modify with powerup
        this.heroes = this.heroes
              .map((hero: Hero) =>
                hero.id === updatedHero.id ? updatedHero : hero
              )
              .sort((a, b) => a.currentPower - b.currentPower)
      // emit the resuelt after every operation 
      this._currentHeroes.next(
        this.herores
      );
    })
  );
  }
```

Remember you have to subscribe to every operation that return an observable like you show in your code.

```
// for example to hero with id 2
this.yourHeroService.powerUp(2).subscribe()
```